# Fast way to check collisions between multiple balls every frame

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, game-physics, physics

Suppose I have `N` moving balls of radius `r` in a 2D space. For simplicity, `N < 30`.

I want to know the fastest way to check if these balls are colliding every frame.

I could obviously do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < N; j++){
        if (dist(ball[i], ball[j]) <= r) CollisionList.Add(i, j);
    }
}
```

But as this is O(N²) and I want to do this every frame, I'd like to ask if there is a faster way. Every frame I want to be able to deal with every collision and compute its consequences.

Comment: Inside unity you can use their implementation of collision detection (OnCollisionEnter and more or OnCollider).
You could even peak into Unity DOTS if that might assist you in improving the optimization further :)

Comment: I'm thinking about using DOTS but I'm writing my own physics. Unity physics is slow and deals with a lot of things I prefer just to ignore.

Comment: Depending on the distribution of the balls over tine you can use a quad tree to isolate groups of balls to smaller areas (quads) however it will only be of benefit if the balls do not congregate, if they do the cost of the quad tree will make it slower than assuming a random distribution and testing each ball against every other. For less than 1000 objects your approach is the simplest and best. There are many other ways to optimize but it all depends on the collective behavior of the balls

Comment: You may find the [Barnes-Hut algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation) useful. PKDGRAV3 and GADGET2 use similar algorithms to reduce N-body gravity calculations to O(N) - you could easily modify that approach to perform collision resolution instead of gravitational calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be asking is the optimal solution to verifying collision between bodies in a simulation (video game). [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection#Optimization) is the long answer.

It's actually a whole discipline to try to find this efficiently and the ball problem is a simpler subset of this kind of problem.

By seeing that your algorithm is O(N²) you saw the actual problem which is choosing the right bodies to test for collision. It's not that simple to implement efficiently, Unity [has that built-in](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-gameObject.html) I think it would be worth checking out (I'm not good with Unity so I can't help you too much with that).

Also, if you're pretty adamant about doing it by yourself I think a good starting point would be [to divide your space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) and check collision only in those small subspaces. There is a [C coded version of that algorithm](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jfc/mirtich/collDet.html) maybe it could guide you or you can use it directly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is super interesting, I'll take a deep look.

Answer (score 2):

Alongside the answer of vdere, maybe you could modify and adapt [the closest pair of points algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-onlogn-implementation/?ref=lbp). Instead of using it to find the pair of points closest to each other, you can try to find all pairs of centers whose distances are less or equal to the sum of the corresponding radii.

Another thing that comes to mind is to keep and update the [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) of the centers of the balls, or maybe another version of it, called the weighted Delaunay triangulation of the centers, where the weights are the radii of the balls. There are different algorithms for generating the (weighted) Delaunay triangulation or its dual version, the [Voronoi Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). See for example [Fortune's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm).